# Method to delete all files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I will probably kick myself after this but I have created a method within my cucumber application that will delete all files in a directory but it doesn't seem to execute as the files still exist after running it, though if i jump into my console and run the commands step by step it works.

Any reason why this would not work when calling the method itself?

```
def clean_reports
  js_error_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/report/js_errors')
  screenshot_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/report/screenshots')
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob(js_error_path + '/*'))
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir.glob(screenshot_path + '/*'))
end
```

What would be handy is if I could just call `FileUtils.rm_rf` just once? is this possible?

My directory structure is like so

```
-cucumber_tests
  -report
   -js_errors
     (files)
   -screenshots
     (files)
```

Thanks

Comment: `puts "#{js_error_path}"` right after it’s assigned — gives you what? BTW, `Dir` accepts enumeration notation: `Dir['report/{js_errors,screenshots}/**/*']`.

Comment: puts outputs './report/js_errors'

Comment: `nil`? It’s virtually impossible because `File.join` is string-aware concatenation function. Anyway, in your environment `File.dirname __FILE__` might reasonably differ from the one you get in console.

Comment: apologies, error on my part, have edited my previous comment

Comment: so would i need to use something different to `File.dirname __FILE__` ? I would rather not hardcode the path as the location of the root directory could be located somewhere different on someone elses machine

Comment: Is it under rails? Then use `Rails.root`. Is it in a gem? Would you mind to update the question with detailes about surrounding directory structure and I’ll provide the descriptive answer.

Comment: As by @jonsnow answer below, the dot `'.'` is actually the best possible solution here, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following line will help,

```
FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir['./report/js_errors', './report/screenshots'])
```

Comment: `Dir['./report/{js_errors,screenshots}']` looks prettier.